# How can I connect FastAPI to ngrok?

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, fastapi, bert-language-model, ngrok

I am fine-tuning [BERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BERT_(language_model)), and I want to deploy my model. I get this very long error, but in short this is the main message:

```
- ERROR 1:    [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('127.0.0.1', 8080): address already in use

- ERROR 2: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in find_recursion(etype, value, records)
    380     # first frame (from in to out) that looks different.
    381     if not is_recursion_error(etype, value, records):
--> 382         return len(records), 0
    383
    384     # Select filename, lineno, func_name to track frames with

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

This is my code:

```
app = FastAPI()
with open('app.py', 'w') as file:
    file.write('''
import streamlit as st
st.write('#Social Media NLP Classifier')
st.write('## Analyze any text and let AI tell you how much it is negative, positive, or neutral')
with st.form(key='my_form'):
    user_input = st.text_input(label='Enter your text')
    submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')

st.write('The score is: ')
with st.echo():
    from transformers import pipeline
    pipe = pipeline("Text Classifier", model=trainer, device=0, return_all_scores=False)
    result = pipe(user_input)
    st.write(result)
    '''
)

ngrok.kill()
ngrok_tunnel = ngrok.connect(8080)
print('Public URL:', ngrok_tunnel.public_url)
nest_asyncio.apply()
uvicorn.run(app, port=8080)
```

Comment: It probably shouldn't be tagged with [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) and [BERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BERT_(language_model)).

Answer (score 0):

When running [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), I run into this problem so often that I have put up a shortcut on my Windows desktop:

[image]

Put this in CMD [to stop](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html) whichever process is engaging your port:

```
NET STOP HTTP
```

If it works, it will break printing functionality of your system, so use the following [to restart](https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html) the printer service:

```
NET START SPOOLER
```

If that doesn't help:

Try running ngork separately first after running the server on your own system. I was doing the same thing when I came across the HTTPS and HTTP issue. FastAPI by default works on HTTP and ngork by default binds to an HTTPS server at the 5000 port.

Try running the FastAPI application on 127.0.0.1:5000 and once it runs, boot up ngork separately.

If it works, figure out a way to run the FastAPI with HTTPS.

P.S: Instead of using port 8080 or 80, use some other, like 5000.